# dsPIC30F2010 reset help

Tags: microcontroller, pic, reset, mplab

I have tried to program a 30f2010 and its got code protected. Showing 0×00000 error.
I have a PicKit2 but didn't know how to use it to reset ic. I've found something like this in the datasheet.  [image]

How can I create it

Comment: You're confusing 'Reset' with 'Erase'. 'Reset' is what happens at every power up or whenever you want the PIC to restart executing is code from the beginning. What you need is to 'Erase' the PIC to clear its code memory and (hopefully) clear the protection settings.

Comment: Sir how can I do 'Erase' the PIC to clear its code memory can you please elaborate.

Comment: Use the same tool which you 1st used to program the PIC.